# iOS Facebook API - Post stories using custom/native UI

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting development of a social app (oxymoron? :p) and wish to implement the Facebook api, however, I want to make use of native iPhone UI (i.e. text fields and buttons) to post stories.
I know it's against their policy to make custom login screens, and I won't do that. Just wish to make my own UI for posting stories and etc.

It kind of breaks my app idea if I can't do this, so really hoping there's a solution.
The dev pages on FB didn't prove much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be done.  Check the samples on the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).  You can prompt the user for the status to be sent, and then post this to /me/feed as per their [API documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)  You will just need to have the user authenticate with your application first and prompt for publish_stream extended permission.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will give this a go later in.